# Year Level/School Level Tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

## Year Level/School Level Tags

---

**Context:**

---

So this question mainly applies to the more academically related sites - the ones that come immediately to mind are Math SE, English SE, Physics SE, etc. - rather than the miscellaneous sites (like Ask Different etc.).

Personally, when browsing questions on MSE I find that the level of questions is quite high - university, post-university level, and the few high school questions which I see scattered amongst them are often buried in a series of more complicated questions.

Now, it's of my opinion (and I'm sure most would agree) that these simpler questions are just as genuine and answer-worthy as the more complicated questions, seeing as they are genuine questions from their askers.

This begs the question, should we really be burying them amongst a ton of questions which at times can frankly be incomprehensibly complicated? Or on the converse side - should we putting these with the higher-level questions? Aren't they just taking space and distracting from the complicated questions that experienced and knowledgeable answerers are looking to answer?

This example thus far has been focused on MSE but I feel that personally, this is a widespread "issue" if you will.

---

**Question:**

---

> Is it not more effective to introduce a series of tags in each site such as  <kbd>Year 12</kbd> , or  <kbd>Secondary School</kbd>, or  <kbd>University</kbd> ?

I think that this could clear the clutter and allow for more focused answering. Someone who can only answer secondary questions but would like to contribute and gain reputation no longer has to search all questions for some easier one, but could simply watch the secondary tags. Those who have been eternally scarred by their secondary years could only answer Uni questions without having to see a bunch of secondary questions in between.

> Or, seeing as there is only 5 tags allowed and this could possibly take up two (i.e.  <kbd>Year 12</kbd>  and  <kbd>Secondary School</kbd> overlap), should we consider adding some built in feature to the question asker whereby before tags, you can choose from a "Year Level Classifier" such as  <kbd>Year 12</kbd> , or  <kbd>Secondary School</kbd>, or  <kbd>University</kbd> ?

---

*Thoughts?*

---

***Thanks!***

---

Comment: How does that relate in any way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercises from answers for learners on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191023/exercises-from-answers-for-learners-on-so) --- The *difficult* questions do have [their own site](https://mathoverflow.net/questions) **if** it can be justified to create a new site; pick any question there and just try to read it, no need to answer. --- The problem with a couple of extra tags is that there's the 5 tag limit. The problem with ***one*** tag is that this has been suggested before  or found to be insulting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336662/3648282.

Comment: @Rob, see the second question, which negates the point about extra tags. I specifically mentioned that.

Comment: I'm not suggesting one tag either. I'm asking about a separate year level classifier.

Comment: Do the downvoters have any feedback?

Comment: See: [What is a “closed” or “duplicate” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/282094) ***and*** [Voting is different on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: See the downvote mouseover text. While you research you will likely find that meta votes can also be agreement/disagreement with proposals. [ask] [help] Please don't be rude, even if it is after jumping to wrong & pessimistic conclusions, or from other people actually being rude. Please inform yourself about how the site works.

Answer (score 8):

No, this wouldn't be a good idea.  It's too subjective and ambiguous.

The biggest problem is that there's not a single time at which everyone learns a given concept.  Should a basic calculus question go in <kbd>secondary-school</kbd> or <kbd>university</kbd>, since it's commonly taught in both?  Other people might learn it via independent study, or as part of postgraduate education in a less math-centric degree.

Ultimately, it ends up being information about the *asker*, rather than about the *question*.  Someone looking to answer more basic questions could filter for tags related to more basic concepts.

Comment: Hmmmm. I'd say there's general standards connotated with secondary-school questions, right? Its not that subjective. You get an idea if it has a "Year 11" tag of what *general* level it will be. And if it is independent studier asking the question, then just don't use the tag!

Comment: I first learned calculus in secondary school, but I've also known people who first learned it in university.  I think you'd have debates over whether questions are "correctly" tagged with the subject matter's grade level, and there wouldn't really be a universally "correct" answer.